# C++ TCL (tree container library): How to traverse a tree from a node straight to root

Tags: c++, traversal, tree-traversal

I am using this library to hold information about tree structure:

http://www.datasoftsolutions.net/tree_container_library/overview.php

Here is simplified version of my C++ code:

```
#include "tcl/sequential_tree.h"

// Node has some data which is not important now

typedef sequential_tree<Node> gametree_t;
typedef sequential_tree<Node>::iterator gametree_iter;

int main() {
    gametree_t gametree;
    gametree_iter gametree_it;

    gametree_it = gametree.insert(Node(0));
    gametree_it->insert(Node(1));
    gametree_it->insert(Node(2));

    gametree_it = gametree_it->insert(Node(3));
    gametree_it->insert(Node(4));

    gametree_it = gametree_it->insert(Node(5));
    gametree_it->insert(Node(6));

    return 1;
}
```

The tree looks like this

```
0
|_ 1
|_ 2
|_ 3
  |_4
  |_5
    |_6
```

I am trying to make a function which given the Node(6) will traverse all the nodes leading to root i.e **6,5,3,0**. This is my first project in C++ and I have trouble understanding pointers. Probably it is a few lines of C++ but I'm trying to do this for a couple of hours with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

something like this works but it must work with many levels not only with 4:

```
gametree_it->get()->get_value();
gametree_it->parent()->get()->get_value();
gametree_it->parent()->parent()->get()->get_value();
gametree_it->parent()->parent()->parent()->get()->get_value();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the common method is to use something like this

```
Node tmp = gametree_it;
while (tmp->parent() != NULL) {
     tmp = tmp->parent();
}
root = tmp->get();
```

Maybe you have to use `while (tmp->has_parent())` or something like that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Otto was right :)

What I ended up using is defining a pointer to gametree. And then traverse the nodes using ->is_root() method.

```
gametree_t* gametree_p;

gametree_p = gametree_it.node();   // gets current node
while (!gametree_p->is_root()) {
   cout << gametree_p->get()->get_value() << endl;
   gametree_p = gametree_p->parent();
}
```